# C++ declaring Caesar Cipher

Tags: c++, debugging, encryption

I get the following error when compiling...

error: ‘text’ was not declared in this scope

error: ‘strlen’ was not declared in this scope

how can i fix this error by declaring them...?

is my code following the rules of Caesar Cipher...

How can I improve this code to make it more efficient???

The program will input file that contains the Caesar cipher, 
and will output the decipher code in another text...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()

{

    // Declarations

    string reply;

    string inputFileName;

    ifstream inputFile;

    char character;



    cout << "Input file name: ";

    getline(cin, inputFileName);



    // Open the input file.

    inputFile.open(inputFileName.c_str());     
    // Check the file opened successfully.

    if ( ! inputFile.is_open()) {

        cout << "Unable to open input file." << endl;

        cout << "Press enter to continue...";

        getline(cin, reply);

        return 1;


    }

    // This section reads and echo's the file one character (byte) at a time.

    while (inputFile.peek() != EOF) {

        inputFile.get(character);

        //cout << character;
    //Don't display the file...

    char cipher[sizeof(character)];


    //Caesar Cipher code...
    int shift;
    do {
        cout << "enter a value between 1-26 to encrypt the text: ";
        cin >> shift;
       } 
    while ((shift <1) || (shift >26));

    int size = strlen(character);
    int i=0;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cipher[i] = character[i];
        if (islower(cipher[i])) {
            cipher[i] = (cipher[i]-'a'+shift)%26+'a';
        }
        else if (isupper(cipher[i])) {
            cipher[i] = (cipher[i]-'A'+shift)%26+'A';
        }
    }

    cipher[size] = '\0';
    cout << cipher << endl;


    }

    cout << "\nEnd of file reached\n" << endl;

    // Close the input file stream

    inputFile.close();

    cout << "Press enter to continue...";

    getline(cin, reply);

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Well, you are using a variable named `text` that was never declared. The error message looks pretty clear to me. For `strlen`, include `string.h` or `stdlib.h` (note that `<string>` and `<string.h>` are two distinct, largely unrelated, headers).

Comment: And how can we suggest improvements if you haven't told us what this program is doing?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik can you tell me where to declared the "text' variable ?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I just added few comment to the program...

Answer (score 1):

Variable `text` was never declared. You might use `char*` or for more convenience `std::string` and use its member function `c_str()` to pass to `strlen`. (Apart from the fact that you could use string's `size()` member function)

Strlen is part of `<cstring>`

```
#include <cstring>
```